# Как загрузить картинку из галереи в ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

Хочу из галереи установить картинку в `ImageView`, падает с ошибкой, как исправить?

***LoadImage.java***

```
public class LoadImage extends Activity {

    private final String TAG = "log_tag";

    private Context context;
    private CircleImageView imageView;

    public LoadImage(Context context, CircleImageView imageView) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_GALLERY = 2;

    public void makePhoto() {

    }

    public void loadGallery(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GALLERY);// ошибка в этой строке
(пробовал менять на context.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GALLERY) но подсвечивает изначально как ошибка)
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CAMERA:

                break;
            case REQUEST_GALLERY:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                        final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                        final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.getMessage();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.nikolai.engadgetnews, PID: 7851
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3918)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
                      at com.example.nikolai.engadgetnews.LoadImage.loadGallery(LoadImage.java:46)
                      at com.example.nikolai.engadgetnews.Profile.Profile$1.onMenuItemClick(Profile.java:96)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu$1.onMenuItemSelected(PopupMenu.java:108)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:156)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:969)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:127)
                      at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3042)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3879)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема с конструктором вашего класса:

```
public LoadImage(Context context, CircleImageView imageView) {
    this.context = context;
    this.imageView = imageView;
}
```

Если бы это был обычный класс, прокатило бы, но это у вас таки `Activity`, а `Activity` так не создаются. Погуглите, как создавать `Activity`, если вкратце, надо сообщить системе, что вы хотите его создать через `Intent`.

Поскольку вы создаете `Activity` неправильно, у вас нет контекста, а раз нет контекста то и создание Intent тоже проваливается.

Answer (score 0):

Вы в правильную сторону шли. Нужно иметь ссылку на context, чтобы вызывать его из адаптера. Если студия показывает ошибку сразу, возможно, вы забыли это поле определить, сохранить в onCreate() и, если вызов происходит в адаптере, передать в адаптер.

```
Context context;
public void onCreate(...) {
    context = this;
    ...

    adapter = new MyAdapter(context);
    ...
}

void loadGaeery(...) {
    ...
    context.startActivity(....);
}
```

Comment: Инициализировал в `onCreate` context, но все равно `context.startActivityForResult(....)` подсвечивает изначально как ошибку/

Comment: Если там что-то про инициализацию, то это вопрос даже не по Android, а по основам Java. По тому коду, который вы показали, у меня нет идей, что у вас не так. Посмотрите внимательней, внутри какого класса вы пытаетесь вызвать этот startActivity(), и что там с доступом к переменной context.